# Neo4J - pass List[String] into query and UNWIND

Tags: scala, neo4j

I am trying to pass a `List[String]` into a query and then match on possibly multiple nodes by a property, where the value of the property is the string passed into the query.

I get an error - `Expected parameter(s): list`

```
import org.neo4j.driver.v1._

def getNodesByPropertyValue(list: List[String]): Future[List[(String, String)]] = {
    val getNodes =
      s"""
         | UNWIND $$list AS propValue
         | MATCH (i: item {id: propValue})<-[:CONTAINS]-(c: Collection)
         | RETURN i.originalID AS OID
         |""".stripMargin
    storeAPI.NeoQuery(getNodes).resultList().map {
      result =>
        result.map {
          record =>
            record.get("OID").toString
        }
    }).recoverWith {
      case e: Exception =>
        logger.error(s"Failure in getNodesByProperty: ", e)
        throw e
    }
  }
```

Also, when I use `$list` instead, I get an error saying Neo4J doesn't recognise the function `List()`.

A solution to this would be appreciated.

Also, what is the difference between passing a variable with `$` into a query, than passing a variable with `$$`? I thought the `$$` might be used for collections but I am unsure, I haven't found information on it yet.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look to [**neotypes**](https://neotypes.github.io/neotypes/) since it is a **Scala** wrapper over the official **Neo4j Java** driver _(which is the one you are using)_ - Disclaimer: I work on that project - BTW, you may also try with `getNodes.asJava` _(you would need to `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._` first)_ since the **Java** driver doesn't know about **Scala** collections but it does know about the **Java** ones.

Answer (score 1):

In my `storeAPI.NeoQuery` I was missing the parameter that maps the string `$$list` in the query, to the val `list` outside of the query.

Working version below.

```
import org.neo4j.driver.v1._

def getNodesByPropertyValue(list: List[String]): Future[List[(String, String)]] = {
val getNodes =
  s"""
     | UNWIND $$list AS propValue
     | MATCH (i: item {id: propValue})<-[:CONTAINS]-(c: Collection)
     | RETURN i.originalID AS OID
     |""".stripMargin
storeAPI.NeoQuery(getNodes, Map("list" -> list.asJava)).resultList().map {
  result =>
    result.map {
      record =>
        record.get("OID").toString
    }
}).recoverWith {
  case e: Exception =>
    logger.error(s"Failure in getNodesByProperty: ", e)
    throw e
}
}
```